# How to generate unique ID for DIV using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, dom, xslt

so I'm able to get the correct titles from my sitecore project:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('title',.)" />
```

^ will spit out the titles I need to use as ID's

Now below is my XSL to generate the HTML modals, there will be 9 modals and I need to add a unique ID to each one. How do you correctly use **generate-id** to add unique id's to each modal? Unique id's using the 'title' captured above?

```
<xsl:for-each select="$TalentUser/item">

    <div class="modal" id="generate-id(sc:fld('title',.))">

        <div class="modal-top">

            <div class="modal-title">
            <label><xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('title',.)" /></label>
            : Select one or more genres below
            </div>

            <div class="modal-closer">
            <a class="simplemodal-close" title="Close"><img src='images/x.png' alt='Close' /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

^ This is my latest code and it just spits out 9 divs, all with the same id

```
<div class="modal" id="generate-id(sc:fld('title',.))">
```

Trying to get something more like

```
<div class="modal" id="Actor">
<div class="modal" id="DJ">
<div class="modal" id="Comedian">
```

etc..

Any tips appreciated!

Another thing I'm trying is this, however running into escaping issues:

```
<div class="modal" id="<xsl:value-of select='sc:fld('title',.)' />">
```

Comment: Note I did find a fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710179/how-to-use-an-incremented-counter-to-provide-a-unique-id-in-xslt However it basically creates ID's like modal-1, modal-2, modal-3. Instead of modal-Actor, modal-DJ which is more ideal for my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Didn't read the last part carefully, therefore deleted previous answer.

It's as simple as:

```
<div class="modal" id="{sc:fld('title',.)}">
```

Are you sure that you never get duplicate IDs like this?  I.e., never two actors/DJs/Comedians?

Comment: Hi! Thx for the reply, so I'm getting my info for Actor, DJ etc from <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('title',.)" /> it's coming out of sitecore. I don't know sitecore either, large ugly looking CMS. Anyways Using a for-loop in XSL I can spit out those 'titles' was just curious if anyone knows how to then use that data to generate div id's with.